# Laravel 4 - Foreach Queries Inside Views for Headers

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to generate a page that will output section headers (retrieved from one table, i.e. a club name) with more data underneath those headers (i.e. club members).

Something like this:

- Header

  - Member 1
  - Member 2
  - Member 3
- Header

  - Member
  - Member

I know this will require 2 foreach controls, but I don't know how to get Laravel to take a query that will have a parameter from another query (e.g. Query 1 provides the clubID, Query2 for the members will take in that clubID from Query 1)

How should I do this while maintaining MVC?

Comment: That's not MVC. Your tree should be built before sending it to a view. The view should not do any querying. Using Eloquent ORM it's quite easy to set up that data structure, then send it to a view and loop through it. Did you read the documentation? Right now your question is too broad. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like related to database and model relationship. Foe example, if you have a table `club_names` and another table `club_members` then you can create a `Club` model like

```
class Club extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'club_names';

    public function members()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Member', 'club_name_id');
    }

}
```

For this to work, your database tables need to be as follows

Table `club_names`

```
id | club_name | other_fields
```

Table `club_members`

```
id | club_name_id | member_name | other_fields
```

Here, `id` of `club_names` table should be foreign key of `club_members` table and if these criterias  met then you can access club members as follows

```
$clubs = Club::with('members')->get();
return View::make('your_view')->with('clubs', $clubs);
```

In your view then you can use

```
@foreach($clubs as $club)
    <div class='club'>
        {{ $club->club_name }}
        @foreach($club->members as $member)
            <div>
                <p>{{ $member->member_name }}</p>
                <p>{{ $member->other_fields }}</p>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Read more about [relationships](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships) on `Laravel` website.

Comment: This is definitely what I'm looking for. What if I'm using a hasManyThrough relationship though? (Say member is just a table holding IDs of another table like officers which has the actual data on members). How would I output that? (I have the query working, btw)

Comment: Actually `hasManyThrough` requires three related tables and first table uses a middle table's field to relate to the third table using that field, if you have a setup like this then you may use this instead.